# jQuery Mobile navbar won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get the navigation bar widget to work at all in my code. I'm building my first  application in notepad++ and I'm trying to learn as I build so I apologize for any simple mistakes.

As of now, it shows up as two 2 row tables with the first showing the first button with a space below it and the second showing a space above it with the 2nd button below it. I've checked the jQuery mobile demo site to try and figure out the code and came up with noting, and so I come to you.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#pagetwo" class ="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                <h2>Summoner Information</h2>
                <h3>Statistics & Achievements</h3><a/></li>
            <li><a href="#todolist">
                <h2>To-Do List</h2>
                <h3>Application wish list</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/navbar -->
</div><!--/header -->
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>This is an ongoing test page for my League of Legends Statistical Analysis and Coaching application</p>
    <p>Please enter your summoner name in the text box below.</p>
    <h2>Enter Your Summoner Name</h2>

    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="search" name="SumName" id="SumName"  placeholder="Summoner Name" data-clear-btn="true"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#pagetwo" id="callSum"  class="ui-btn" >Search</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in closing tag of anchor. you have used like `<a/>` instead of `</a>`

Update your code like below.

```
  <li><a href="#pagetwo" class ="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
      <h2>Summoner Information</h2>
      <h3>Statistics & Achievements</h3></a>   
  </li>
```